# How can i restrict access to my firebase so that only I - the owner can access it

Tags: firebase

I find my self very confused.

My task is very simple, i want to use Firebase with node.js so that only i will be able to access the base.

Usually services gives a sort of a key so that only the owner can login to the base.

Why isn't this possible? I don't need any authentication for users in my case, so i find the documentation very confusing since i don't need any authentication except for not allowing anyone else than me to access the base.

This is not supposed to be done via a 3rd party provider, this should be allowed directly from your service.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried to disable the read / write access and use only the server token?

Comment: where do i get the server toekn??? right now everyone can write some node.js code and get access to my base.

Comment: @lobengula3rd you need to spend some time in [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/); this is a sophisticated BaaS and you'll want to familiarize yourself with the basics. Here's the [security portion](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. so i managed to find the solution.

In you account you have the tab security rules which you should change to:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

Now go to the tab Secrets and you will find your auth key.

Now in the node.js code do:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/");
// Log me in.
dataRef.auth(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!");
  }
});
```

This is confused me a little since they are talking about users, but i didn't think of my self (owner) as a user accessing the base.

Comment: To Firebase, a user is a client connecting to the data, so there's no distinction between users of your app and server processes. Whilst using the secret directly as an authentication method works, it means any reads or writes from your server will bypass any security rules or validation. The best practice is to create a one-off token using one of our [token generator libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries) with a `uid` of something like 'server' so that you can reference `auth.uid === 'server'` in your security rules